# The Faq Has a Broken Link

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

Currently the first link in the [FAQ](https://stackapps.com/faq) points to `http://dev.stackapps.com/?tab=apps`.  It should link to `https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps`.

Simple fix, but it confused me for a short time.

Comment: since this is about the stack apps site itself and not the api, shouldn't this go on meta.stackoverflow.com? (I'll admit I'm guilty of not adhering to that myself though)

Comment: @Kyle I agree that it doesn't belong here.  But it doesn't belong on meta (regular meta) either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.